# Facebook Authentication throws Errors for a few Users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, oauth-2.0

I am working with a team to build a Facebook game. For one of the people on the team, it will throw errors and not get his id or data. It works for everyone else that has tested, ~20 people.

The error that is thrown:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=165114483572553&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F
(*INSERT APP*)%2F&client_secret=(*SECRET_CODE*)&code=AQBnvIjs0jaUnoUKkjsh3K7G7JK
QYMrIx525Jn6jYmDtWS74nEa_TTZf6e4p7jPadyjaS9t-M_GXGFFg_K8r6MZtUdWr4C6MRUR6p
COgqN5YqWXNVqlbyfmFJcrKlsu2D4oUQ4YkKNIDw-vaij4s_dliKnzndJwFs7i0
gL2J5a3229fgdCkU2Jps8YnKNMUsD-A) 
[function.file-get-contents ((*INSERT SECURE URL*))]: failed to open stream: 
HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in (*URL/*)game/index.php on line 24

Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=) 
[function.file-get-contents ((SECURE_URL)/game/function.file-get-contents)]: 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in 
(SECURE_URL)/game/index.php on line 31
```

**EDIT: The Code I forgot to post.**

**EDIT2: Removed old code. Added updated code and more detail.**

```
<?php
    $app_id = "(ID)";
    $canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/(APP)/";
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    $auth_url = GetCH();

    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);  

    if (empty($data["user_id"])) 
    {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
    } 
    else 
    {
        include_once 'game.php';
    }

    function GetCH()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={appd_id}&redirect_uri={$canvas_page}");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS,20000);
        if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://')
        {
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        }
        $sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $sendCH;
    }
```

This is my index page. Facebook loads this when someone opens the app. From here I include game.php that has the background and swf files. The SWF calls database.php which loads their information into the game. saveplayer.php saves the game. Is this possibly and issue with the database.php as I'am having trouble with that as well.

**EDIT 3:**
Database.php

```
<?php

    error_log("database");
    include 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '165114483572553',
        'secret' => 'c65114e7dbc8b1eeed9f6535c1aee888',
    ));

    try
    {
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');  
    }

    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }

    try 
        {
                //$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
                mysql_connect("localhost", "(USER)", "(PASS)") or die("Could not connect");
            mysql_select_db("stus_zombies") or die("Could not select database");

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE facebook_id = " . $user_profile[id]);  
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

            if(empty($result))
            { 
                $addInfo = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, facebook_id) 
                VALUES ('{$user_profile['first_name']}','{$user_profile['last_name']}','{$user_profile['id']}')");  
                    $addInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());  

                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (facebook_id, coins, health, stamina, xp)
                VALUES ('{$user_profile['id']}','0','25','25','0')");
            }

            $checkProgress = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE facebook_id = " . $user_profile[id]);
            $playerCheck = mysql_fetch_array($checkProgress);

            $playerInfo = array(
            first_name => $user_profile[first_name],
                last_name => $user_profile[last_name],
                facebook_id => $user_profile[id], 
                coins => $playerCheck[coins],
            health => $playerCheck[health],
            stamina => $playerCheck[stamina],
            xp => $playerCheck[xp],); 

            echo json_encode($playerInfo);
    }

    catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
        error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
```

Comment: Please please use curl http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mob mentioned you should use curl to retrieve access tokens for your app.  I use the below method.  This may not resolve the issue with your user, i would have the user re-authenticate, but it will resolve the issue of exposing your app's secret when an error occurs.

> When adding to a url all you need is /?app_access_token  it includes
>   the acess_token=############.

---

```
function GetCH(){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app_id}&client_secret={secret}&grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS,20000);
if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://'){
    // The following ensures SSL always works. A little detail:
    // SSL does two things at once:
    //  1. it encrypts communication
    //  2. it ensures the target party is who it claims to be.
    // In short, if the following code is allowed, CURL won't check if the 
    // certificate is known and valid, however, it still encrypts communication.
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
}
$sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $sendCH;
};
$app_access_token = GetCH();
```

Comment: Alright, I've got this code working and it fixed another issue I was having. Didn't solve this problem though. I'm sure it has something to do with Authentication or cookies. I will update to the code I am using now. Oddly, if I query the user and write the data to the error log, it works correctly. Its only passing it through the game that has issues, but I know that the Flash side is working correctly.

Comment: i should have asked, what version of php-sdk are you using.

Comment: The newest one as of last Friday. Would have to check the exact number. (3.1.1)

Comment: is this the full code?  i do not see where you are initializing php-sdk.

Comment: Added the class that initializes the php-sdk.

Comment: I'll add it here since it isn't visible yet. Unless you can see it?

Comment: edit into your original question, i am still confused about what the actual error your getting is.  I think maybe we need to be more clear on the errors.

Comment: The Database class is waiting for verification.

There normally is no error, aside from it not working. Yesterday tried a few different ways of authenticating the player, one of them threw this error.

[07-Nov-2011 13:00:22] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
  thrown in (OMITTED)/src/base_facebook.php on line 1039

Comment: did you run that users user-access_token in the debugger? - that error is thrown when a user is not authenticated to an app that is trying to make an api call that requires a user access_token. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Its not even calling the page it should be atm so I can't get the access_token. No errors are being thrown, and I have it set to write to the error_log when the page is loaded up but there is nothing.

Comment: have you made a test page, with just the graph-api calls to help dubug the errors?  Make a page with just the graph-api calls, and a few echos with a login link and i will help you test it.

  7 more rep for you and we can take this to chat, would be alil faster lol.

Comment: Ok, I will set that up. Won't let me go to chat yet though... I really appreciate all your help with this.

Comment: Ok, all set up. Sorry about the wait.

http://zombies.stuartandrewsaunders.com/game/test.php

Comment: It works for the guy with issues as well. It seems to be a problem with calling the script from Flash. It works well for everyone else, but it doesn't even write that it was called when he loads up the game. Same with the saveplayer script, which is called by a button press. It never writes that to the log either. The database.php and saveplayer.php scripts are not used until they are called by Flash. Would that throw Authentication off or something? Is it maybe an issue for people with more strict Facebook settings?

Comment: This is begining to sound like a flash issue, if the flash file calling the api on same server and on same domain?  I also just seen you calling this from local host?  Can you try this from live environment?

Comment: Yes it is. Possible issues could be Facebook calling the secured version of the link, and the app calling the unsecured. I have tried both but either way it seems to cut in and cut out at its own will (for everybody). My webhost has shared ssl so that would be a different domain if Facebook calls that. I will switch everything over to the secured url again and see what happens.

Comment: if the domains match your application domain settings on everything you should not have issues, but if say i try to make the call from www.ShawnsSpace.com it will fail.  "but should error with domain does not own application.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure its not a Flash issue, because if I put dummy information into the files it will work correctly.

Comment: Well that totally worked. I can't believe I spent days working on that. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: One more quick question. Currently I'm using the PHP-SDK on the index page to authenticate. I assume the need to use cURL is negated because of this, correct?

Comment: i am not sure i understand the question.  I suggested to use cURL only to get you app_access_token when needed, and suggested it because if you use file get contents and it fails your secret key will be exposed to the user.

Comment: You can use cURL with the php-sdk if that is what your asking, it will auth and pass the cookie just fine, even if from another domain.

Comment: here is an example, cURL my plugin to a test page  https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/timelinefeed.php  it will auth, get the app_access_token for my app server side and load the feed on your page just fine :-)  my plugin is pure php-sdk.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answers. I just wanted to make sure the PHP-SDK wouldn't throw any errors that might display private data.