# PHP file_get_contents() error - return URL needs authenticating with basic auth

Tags: php, file-get-contents, basic-authentication

> file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=777445576857891&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.org%2Fsocialmedia%2Ffacebook%2Fcontroller.php&client_secret=e65302ed939a9150ab718720aae923fe&code=AQAMoaETajPO7s5eLSIQJ1yaOJHqSqRlY1SIGU5ZOxmjC-L93ukpw9Fg3jP8mGOhaiHIACFDQ02O9FW3ikfi90SjiuxpK_IPqTj9kRdRU9PTWn3Yapm_E9k2zh_k7zm48NH5yGiha9FpdkiOVzpBrAL_Q5DvCZXaqa9rnYfSwxctteyf_AJ66Cn0UprRGz0-acs#*=*&display=popup)
>   [function.file-get-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

I get the above error and think this is because the URL set for  `redirect_uri`

requires authentication.  How do I add the username and password to the URL?

*EDIT*  I have changed the redirect_uri to one that does not require authentication and still dos not work.  Also changed the Site URL within Facebook Developer App setup.

Also tried using CURL as a few people have suggested and nothing is returned, no error messages and no access token.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080037/php-file-get-contents-error-page-needs-authenticating

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017062/facebook-authentication-throws-errors-for-a-few-users

Answer (score 1):

Basically: `http://username:password@host.example.com/...`

But maybe you can try the Facebook API.

Comment: Tried tried adding the username and passwords as set out above to the redirect_uri parameter but still  get errors.

Comment: file_get_contents on external urls is quite evil. you shoudn't do it. use a socket or the facebookapi

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna start here: http://developers.facebook.com/

On a side note, try using cURL functions instead of file_get_contents. It's faster:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

Comment: Thanks Ive already read through http://developers.facebook.com/ and am using the code from there which is using file_get_contents() but am at a loss to undertsnad why its not working.